# Specify a range of text for Google Sheets Conditional Formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I would like Google Sheets to look at a column and highlight a cell red if it contains any of the letters A through M.  My current solution is using a Custom Formula that looks like this =or(D4="a",D4="b",D4="c", and so on).

I'm wondering if anyone can think of a way to do it without so many arguments.  To somehow specify the range of letters A through M.

Comment: I recommend phrasing questions more carefully. You wrote "A through M" but then your example has letters a, b, c which are not in the range A-M.  Also, "cell contains a letter A-M" could be understood as "the text in the cell contains a letter A-M", which would mean that "Argh" should match.

Comment: Hey Norman - thanks.  The "or" rule I was using worked for both lower and uppercase letters, so I got a little lazy with my precision of language.  Your solution is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know, I'll use [regular expressions](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en).

Conditional formatting (say, applied to the block A1:Z) with custom formula

```
=regexmatch(A1,"^[A-M]$")
```

highlights the cells with a single upper case letter from A to M. Similarly,  the formula

```
=regexmatch(A1,"^[a-m]$")
```

matches lowercase a-m, and

```
=regexmatch(A1,"^[A-Ma-m]$")
```

matches either case.

#### Explanation

- ^ asserts position at the beginning of the string
- [...] requires exactly one character from the specified character group
- $ asserts position at the end of the string

Without ^ and $, the expression would match any string containing at least one character from the specified group.